# CDI Extension class makes Wildfly container bean discovery fail

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, cdi, custom-scope

In preparation for adding a custom CDI scope, I have added a class that implements the CDI spi Extension interface. The class has no code in it:

```
public class TaskScopedExtension implements Extension, Serializable {
}
```

Simply including the class in the deployment causes all of the other CDI bean discovery to fail. I have not added any other code or files. Apparently Wildfly scans the deployment looking for the Extension, but I can't figure out why just including the class would cause the rest of the injections to fail. I haven't found anything helpful in the Java EE or Weld documentation. I have tried adding Observables on the before and after bean discovery events, and I have tried adding the javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension file to the deployment. Neither of those seems to make a difference.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are running into one very peculiar part of the specification. Perhaps a leftover retained for backward compatibility. It is section [12.1 Bean Archives](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bean_archive) - "*An archive which contains an extension and no beans.xml file is not a bean archive.*"

Add `beans.xml` with desired discovery mode (or even empty one) and you should have it operational again.